# Destroy WebAssembly instance?

Tags: javascript, webassembly

Is there a way to destroy a running Web Assembly instance after instantiating it?

e.g. instantiated via any of these:

```
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming()
WebAssembly.instantiate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasm instance objects are automatically garbage-collected, like everything else on the JS heap. Anything belonging to the module that is no longer used is likewise collected.

Why would you want to destroy them explicitly?

Edit: Based on your comments it sounds like your real question is how to interrupt running Wasm code because it might have an infinite loop. The answer is: that is not possible. The web platform has no mechanism for programmatically interrupting or killing execution. Creating infinite loops is a design bug in a web app.

Comment: I'm building a playground/"fiddle" for a [3D engine written in Go](https://github.com/g3n/engine) - you can write Go code in the browser, compile it to Web Assembly and run it. Everything works except that every time a snippet is executed and a new WebAsssembly instance is created the used memory increases because the previous instance(s) are still running. Running a snippet a few times crashes the page due to the WASM memory limit (4GB). I can't rely on the snippet author to make sure their program exits, and in most cases programs will not exit because they have a rendering loop.

Comment: I don't see why the instances would still be "running". If your JS code drops all references to those instances and their exports then they should be reclaimed. Perhaps your JS code accidentally keeps some of them reachable and alive longer than you intend, thereby creating the space leak you observe?

Comment: The instances keep running because there is an infinite loop inside the WASM code i.e. the render loop. No references external to WASM are kept as far as I can tell.

Comment: Well, infinite loops in a browser app are a design bug. The web platform has no mechanism for interrupting running code, neither in Wasm nor in JS. If you want to avoid user code to run into infinite loops then you'll probably have to inject some termination condition.

Comment: *The web platform has no mechanism for programmatically interrupting or killing execution.* Does this implicitely excludes WebWorkers somehow? Because there, it is definitely possible to kill an infinite loop from outside ([Worker.terminate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/terminate)) and while I'm no WA expert at all, I wonder what happens to WA instance, started from a Worker that gets terminated this way...

Comment: @Kaiido, right, I think terminate kills the entire worker process, so that should free any resources held by it. But I'm not sure the OP is using workers, since they mention it being a render loop. OTOH, I don't see how any Wasm could be running in the background without being a worker. Perhaps more information is needed. I suspect the actual issue might involve the Go runtime and its implementation of lightweight threading.

Comment: After some pruning I figured out exactly which Go code makes the memory hang. It's when I register the requestAnimationFrame callback. If I call `os.Exit(1)` before that, the entire WASM memory is deallocated but if I call it after, it hangs. The JS engine must be keeping an internal reference to the WASM function, which I can't remove without knowing the `requestID` issued when it was registered.

Comment: I don't know how Go implements os.Exit on the browser, or how you register the callback from Go, but I have the strong suspicion that the Go runtime is the culprit.

Comment: What if you want. to reinstantiate the Wasm Instance every time you screen resize? Will the garbage collection really kick in at the right time?

Comment: @Adminy, define "at the right time". Modern GCs are incremental, they do not kick in at specific points in time but sort of run constantly in the background, doing small slices of work. In browsers, they also detect idle times, at which they can do more work because nothing else is happening.

Comment: I mean it's garbage collecting an entire environment and its not like there is a destroy api with a promise attached for when its done